# Create a set of numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, set

I want to create a set of numpy arrays and then efficiently perform the `in` operation.

```
explored = {
       np.array([[4,9,6,1,2,5], [5,8,3,7,7,9], [2,4,1,6,3,8]]),
       np.array([[1,2,3,1,2,5], [1,2,3,7,7,9], [1,2,3,6,3,8]]),
           }

if array in explored: # where array is an np.array 
    print("the array is already in the set")
else:
    explored.append(array)
```

But the interpreter complains that `np.array` is not a hashable type. What can I do instead?

Comment: What is `array` in `if array in explored:`?

Comment: To be placed into a `set` an object has to be immutable.  A set is like the keys of a dictionary.  Thus a `tuple` can used, but a `list` can't.  An `array` is like a list in that elements can be changed, and thus it doesn't have a unique 'hash'.

Comment: Clarify what kind of `in` testing you want.  You show two (2,6) arrays.  What would make another array the same?  Same shape? dtype, exact (integer) values?  Or same array object id?  `np.in1d` is one of several array `set` functions.  `np.unique` is another.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First get a regular np.array:

```
explored = np.array([[4,9,6,1,2,5], [5,8,3,7,7,9], [2,4,1,6,3,8]])
```

Then `explored` is

```
np.array([[4,9,6,1,2,5], [5,8,3,7,7,9], [2,4,1,6,3,8]])
```

Then convert that to a set. But to do that, convert each row in the np.array to a tuple, so it is hashable.

```
explored_set = {tuple(row) for row in explored}
```

Now `explored_set` is

```
{(2, 4, 1, 6, 3, 8), (4, 9, 6, 1, 2, 5), (5, 8, 3, 7, 7, 9)}
```

Now you can use that for searches:

```
if tuple(array) in explored_set:
    # processing here
```

And so on. Note that the order of the set differs from the order of the np.array, as is typical.

Comment: And change `explored.append(array)` to `explored.add(tuple(array))` since it is now a set.

Comment: @Alexander: I did not understand just what processing the OP was attempting, so I left that to him. But you are correct, if that is what the OP is trying for, after changing name `explored` to `explored_set`.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Each 2D array was an element of the set, instead of there being 3 elements in the original set I provided. However the general principle of "turn to tuple, hash that" worked just as fine in the case I was interested in